# View Unicode characters in Xcode console?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I need to see some string with Unicode characters in the Xcode console when I do `NSLog(@"some unicode characters..")`. Eg: `abc\u0001xyz\u0002pqr`… But Xcode console only shows the `abcxyzpqr`. It doesn't show the intermediate Unicode characters. Does anyone know how to view this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know, it's a long time since you asked but try this if you're still looking for an answer :

```
NSString *demo=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:
                   [NSData dataWithBytes:myUnicodeString length:itsLength]
                     encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",demo);
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSString* strOld=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",responseObject];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString
             stringWithCString:[strOld cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
             encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSString *string = @"Hi \u00B7 there!";

 lblString.text=string;
```

Comment: its  not the answer. you need a proper encoding for formatting unicode character. check the answer , it uses a encoding "NSUnicodeStringEncoding" for converting unicode (which is in nsdata formar) characters to string.