# Showing unicode in the console in the right format

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

```
NSSet *subFolders = [_account subscribedFolders];
NSLog(@"subFolders: %@",subFolders);
```

Output:

```
...
    "[Gmail]/\U05d8\U05d9\U05d5\U05d8\U05d5\U05ea",
    "[Gmail]/\U05d7\U05e9\U05d5\U05d1" 
...
```

Is there any way I can show the above text in its original language (Hebrew) ?

Things I tried:

- changing the debugger from LLDB to GDB - Didn't work
- Checking under preferences -> Text Editing UTF-* is selected

Thanks

Comment: maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372103/view-unicode-characters-in-xcode-console

Comment: Tried it ,I can't encode the NSSet, I guess it would work for NSString which is not the case.

Comment: you can try NSString *desc = [yourNSSet description];

Comment: Tried to do something like this `NSString *desc = [subFolders description];
    NSString *demo=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:
                    [NSData dataWithBytes:(__bridge const void *)(desc) length:[desc length]]
                                         encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",demo);` And it wouldn't even print the word demo. I got a warning for using desk inside initWithData so I tried using the __bridge but that didn't helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue with displaying unicode characters in the console, so I would assume it's the way the string is getting into the set in the first place.

I would suggest iterating over all the objects inside subFolders with something like:

```
 for( id object in [subFolders allObjects] ) {
    //Print out the name of the item explicitly
 }
```

Even if this doesn't work, it at least lets you work with the strings directly.  If it's still printing out:

> "[Gmail]/\U05d8\U05d9\U05d5\U05d8\U05d5\U05ea"

It would look as if you're being sent escaped unicode characters, and I would suggest this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7861345/352891 - this may work directly on NSSet's description

Comment: Your second solution with the NSSet's description worked great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSString* strOld=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",responseObject];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString
             stringWithCString:[strOld cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
             encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

Comment: Could you explain why that helps the OP?

Comment: Perfect Answer. Worked like a charm